# Relative Path issue in shell script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I am having trouble creating path reference in shell scripts.

---

I have 1 parent folder, which has 2 child folders.

```
Directory Structure =>

Parent
    |
    -- Child1 (contains shell script start)
    |
    -- Child2 (contains python files)
```

---

Now inside `Child1`, I have `start.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/usr/bin/python ../Child2/code1.py
```

---

**Problem :**

When I `cd` into `Child1` and run the `start.sh`, it works perfectly.

But when I run `start.sh` from anyother directory (say `/home/`), the relative path reference in the shell script complains. It says `No file found`, and this is because it is using `/home/` and using that as relative path. I have tested this by doing an `echo $pwd`

I have tried `$pwd' & '$cwd'. It does not help.

My aim is to have this shell script to work from anydirectory. How can I achieve this?

---

Looking forward to some help here. I would be happy to add more information if needed.

Comment: why not pass a full path?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "it complains"?  What exactly is the error you are getting, and exactly what command are you executing?

Comment: The current working directory (which is what relative paths are considered relative *to*) is independent of where the file resides.

Comment: @Greg - I have added the error explanation.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - the parent folders location is not decided, and can be kept anywhere. Using the fullpath will not be suitable for my usecase.

Comment: @chepner - thanks for pointing this duplicate. It had the solution `pushd 'dirname $0' > /dev/null \
SCRIPTPATH='pwd' \
popd > /dev/null`